# Spring Boot App on AWS Continious Deployment with GitHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

I'm learning how work with AWS, and now I'm trying to do a codepipeline connecting AWS and GitHub (a spring boot jar applicacion). I have connected with GitHub and compile the sources but the deployment fails.

[image]

This is the error showed in the pipeline:

[image]

I have gone to the log that specify the error and find this other description:

```
2022/05/09 20:38:31.199534 [INFO] Job for web.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status web.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

2022/05/09 20:38:31.199559 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [FlipApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: Register application failed because the registration of proc web failed: 
startProcess Failure: starting process "web" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start web.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for web.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status web.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

But I don't understand. I looking in the web and try but it still not work. I have change the version from pom.xm already.
This is the buildspec.yml that I use:

```
version: 0.2
 
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
    commands:
      - echo install
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo pre_build
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn package
      - echo build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo post_build

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
    - target/02-todo-rest-api-h2-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I add the codepipeline configuration's summary:

[image: Step 1: Choose pipeline settings]
[image: Step 2: Add source stage]
[image: Step 3: Add build stage]
[image: Step 4: Add deploy stage]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The error message you posted recommends running `journalctl -xe` to see more detailed logs.

Comment: yes @jordanm, But i'm so new that I donk know where I have to execute the command

Comment: Typically you would run that on the target server via ssh, the one with the instance ID in the screenshot. I unfortunately don't know much about elastic beanstalk and how its deployments function.

Comment: ook, With that on mind I think that now I can work and find more information about it. Thanks I will check it. Thanks

Comment: Update: I changed the platform of the evironment to Java 8, the previous was Correto 11 and 8. In this way it works fine. But What do I ignore with correto 8 or 11? Which configs have to I do to it works?